Using Haystack and Ollama . ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ollama'
I'm running an example from the haystack website here
I have used poetry to add ollama-haystack
I am running the following code using Python 3.12.3 on WSL2 ubuntu 24.04
from haystack_integrations.components.embedders.ollama import OllamaTextEmbedder

embedder = OllamaTextEmbedder()

result = embedder.run(text="What do llamas say once you have thanked them? No probllama!")

print(result['embedding'])

I am getting an error:
 File "/home/../.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/haystack_integrations/components/embedders/ollama/document_embedder.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ollama import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ollama'

My python is a bit rusty so apologies if the error is obvious.

You need to install module on WSL2 ubuntu 24.04
pip install ollama-haystack

https://pypi.org/project/ollama-haystack/

Thanks , but I've already done that   in my question "I have used poetry to add ollama-haystack"

You're right ,  I made another virtual env using venv and pip installed the dependency and BOOM it worked. I'll have to go back and see what I'm doing wrong with poetry . Many thanks
